# show div only on dropdown selection and keep it after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to keep after refreshing page, a div that show only on dropdown selection

this is my demo http://jsfiddle.net/QTdS4/

Now its working but if I refresh the page and the company was selected the additional field is not showing, I have to select the first option than reselect the company option in order for the additional field to show

what I want to do is to keep the additional field if the user selected company and refreshed the page.

here is my ht ml structure

```
<select name="agencyselect" id="agencyselect">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Agency</option>
<option value="1">Company</option>
</select>
<div class="control-group" id="companyname" style="display:none;">
    <label class="control-label" for="companyname">Company Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input id="s_companyname" type="text" name="s_companyname" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and my javascript

```
    window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('agencyselect').addEventListener('change', function () {
        if (this.value == 1) {
            document.getElementById('companyname').style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('companyname').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }, false)
};
```

note that I do not want to use jquery

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/QTdS4/

Comment: use the session storage to manage this http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: can you help me implemented - im new to javascript and trying to learn as I go, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have an implementation with the HTML5 `sessionStorage` and without jQuery:

```
window.onload = function () {

  var agencySelect = document.getElementById('agencyselect'),
      companyName = document.getElementById('companyname');

  console.log(sessionStorage.agencyselect);

  if (sessionStorage.agencyselect == 1) {
    agencySelect.selectedIndex = 1;
    companyName.style.display = 'block';
  }

  agencySelect.addEventListener('change', function () {
    sessionStorage.agencyselect = agencySelect.value;

    if (this.value == 1) {
      companyName.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      companyName.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }, false);

};
```

A working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QTdS4/1/

More about Web Storage (`sessionStorage`) see the W3C specification: http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#introduction

Comment: Works perfectly, Im gonna read more about webstorage, looks interesting! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

this is a quick implementation

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#agencyselect").val(localStorage.getItem("selectedPreference"));
   if (localStorage.getItem("selectedPreference") == "1") {
        $('#companyname').css({"display":'block'});
    } else {
         $('#companyname').css({"display":'none'});
   }

  $("#agencyselect").on("change",function(e){
     console.log($(this).val());
     localStorage.setItem("selectedPreference",$(this).val());
  });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/La9vF/2/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have tried it but its not showing the extra field anymore when I press on the company- any idea why?

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked but using jquery, iwas hoping to make it without the use of jquery as my client project don't want to use jquery, is this can be done using pure javascript? Thanks a lot for your answers

Comment: can you please help me with it , im new to javascript, still learning - Thanks again - also I tried it on my site without jquery but didn't work - what would be the code to make it work with js only?

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to save user's selected value to somewhere (such as query string) and restore back when refreshing page.

Try this:

```
// Get name/value pair from query string
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

// Set name/value pair to query string
function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
  var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
  var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
  if (uri.match(re)) {
    return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
  }
  else {
    return uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var agent = document.getElementById('agencyselect');
    var company = document.getElementById('companyname');

    agent.addEventListener('change', function () {
        window.location.href = updateQueryStringParameter(window.location.href, "agentId", this.value);
    }, false);

    var agentId = getParameterByName("agentId");
    agent.value = agentId;
    if (agentId == 1) {
        company.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        company.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```